# Image thumbnail is not displaying when sharing product URL via inbox

Tags: magento2, product-images, thumbnail

When we share link for any product via inbox, image thumbnail is not rendered.

This is the screenshot about issue:
https://snipboard.io/AwDtXU.jpg
https://snipboard.io/85kFXW.jpg

Anyone help me this problem.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in few steps to add a preview for WhatsApp, Twitter, Facebook and bookmark icons for pc's and mobile devices.

Reference: [ogp.me](http://ogp.me)

**Step 1: title**

Maximum of 65 characters

```
<title>your keyword rich title of the website and/or webpage</title>
```

---

**Step 2: description**

Maximum of 155 characters

```
<meta name="description" content="description of your website/webpage, make sure you use keywords!">
```

---

**Step 3: og:title**

Maximum 35 characters

```
<meta property="og:title" content="short title of your website/webpage" />
```

---

**Step 4: og:url**

Full link to the current webpage address

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/webpage/" />
```

---

**Step 5: og:description**

Maximum 65 characters

```
<meta property="og:description" content="description of your website/webpage">
```

---

**Step 6: og:image**

Image(JPG or PNG) with a size less than 300KB and minimum dimensions of 300 x 200

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//cdn.example.com/uploads/images/webpage_300x200.png">
```